# Android device boot into the operating system when USB power adapter is plugged in

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-hardware, android-usb, android-powermanager

I would like to have my Android device boot into the operating system when I plug in the USB power adapter. Solutions are available on SO that involve editing "/system/bin/lpm" as shown below.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

Variations on the filename have been noted as "../playlpm", as well as "../ipod". However none of these files are present in recent CyanogenMod builds.

I've checked all of the files in /system/bin/, but have found none specific to lpm (low power manager). Consequently, none of the previously posted solutions to this problem are applicable.

Suggestions on resolving this situation? TIA

Comment: better if you ask this in xda-developers

Comment: And you expect the guys who answer on programming problems to find you an easier solution than that?